# Changing x86 to x64 affects my LNK1168 Error

Tags: c++

So I created a code in C++ using visual studio and I was learning about making classes and using methods/functions. The program was working fine until I wrote the  `using namespace std;` and suddenly trying to run my code I got a LNK1168 error and I tried everything to fix it.

I made sure that no tasks were running, and I saved it and closed it and opened it back up to run it again and still no matter what I did, the LNK1168 error pops back up.

I then switched from debugging x86 to debugging x64 and my code works normally with the x64.

Does this matter? If so why, if not then what should I do?

```
#include<iostream>

// did not include the using namespace std; because that's when my issue started 
// not sure if it had something to do with it

class Player
{
public:
    int x, y;
    int speed;


void movin(int xa, int ya)
{
    x += xa * speed;
    y += ya * speed;
}

};



int main()
{

    Player player;

    player.movin(1, 1);

    std::cout << "apples are tasty";  // this is to make sure my code prints something


    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried looking up youtube videos but nothing helps! Oddly enough the x64 works but not the usual x86? Does this affect my code or how I compile my code? Would it make things run slower? I am confused.
I tried looking at the Windows Help site after clicking the error and nothing helps. Does anyone know?

Comment: You might be done some other changes. The above code with the 'namespace std' statement in x86 and x64 is running successfully at my end on VisualStudio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

[LNK1168](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1168?view=vs-2019) Means your executable is still running when you try to compile the code. Close the app, and then compile.

Comment: What do you mean, like I exit out of everything and reopened my file, I then debugged it on x86 I get error but I do not when it is x64. If by app you mean my output window, I closed out of that and compile and it error still appears.